# Parse html with PdfMake-wrapper

Tags: angular, pdf, pdfmake

I'm developing an angular website that has to create a pdf and I'm using PdfMake-wrapper (https://github.com/Lugriz/pdfmake-wrapper).

This is my function:

```
async pdf() {

PdfMakeWrapper.setFonts(pdfFonts);
const pdf = new PdfMakeWrapper();

pdf.pageSize('A4');
pdf.pageMargins([40, 60, 40, 60]);
pdf.pageOrientation('portrait');

pdf.header(this.bando.name);

pdf.add('Descrizione Bando');
pdf.add(this.bando.desc);

pdf.create().download();

}
```

The problem is that "this.bando.desc" is html text (it contains table, div ecc..) and I'd like to format my pdf like my html.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to NOT create the PDF directly, because it requires a lot of formatting that differs from HTML. Better create a HTML-Document and then convert this to a PDF afterwards. I used this in one of my recent projects (printing mtg card decks) and it is working really well:

```
import pdfkit
from jinja2 import Template, Environment, FileSystemLoader


class Html(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.template: Optional[Template] = None

    def load_template(self):
        template_loader = FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
        template_env = Environment(loader=template_loader)
        self.template = template_env.get_template("template.html")

    def write_html(self, deck_name: str, data: list):
        with io.open("index.html", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
            if self.template:
                fh.write(self.template.render(deck_name=deck_name, rows=data))

class Pdf(object):
    def __init__(self, deck_name: str):
        self.deck_name = deck_name
        self.options = {
            'margin-left': '5mm',
            'margin-right': '5mm',
            'margin-top': '5mm',
            'margin-bottom': '5mm',
        }

    def create(self):
        # create pdf
        pdfkit.from_file('index.html', f'{self.deck_name}.pdf', options=self.options)

html = Html()
html.load_template()
html.write_html(deck_name=deck_name, data=rows)
pdf = Pdf(deck_name=deck_name)
pdf.create()
```

I guess the code will not run without any changes, because I just tried to strip it down to the essential functions, but you can get an idea how it works.

It uses `Jinja2` as template engine for easy formatting and then `pdfkit` module to export the html to pdf with `wkhtmltopdf`, which can be downloaded from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/